# Resnet Model taking too long to train

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using [this](https://github.com/priya-dwivedi/Deep-Learning/blob/master/resnet_keras/Residual_Network_Keras.ipynb) tutorial to learn transfer learning for my model. As we can see that his single epoch was of 1 sec average.

```
Epoch 1/100
1080/1080 [==============================] - 10s 10ms/step - loss: 3.6862 - acc: 0.2000
Epoch 2/100
1080/1080 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 3.0746 - acc: 0.2574
Epoch 3/100
1080/1080 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 2.6839 - acc: 0.3185
Epoch 4/100
1080/1080 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 2.3929 - acc: 0.3583
Epoch 5/100
1080/1080 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 2.1382 - acc: 0.3870
Epoch 6/100
1080/1080 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 1.7810 - acc: 0.4593
```

But when I am following almost same code for my cifar model, my single epoch is taking about 1 hour to run.

```
Train on 50000 samples
 3744/50000 [=>............................] - ETA: 43:38 - loss: 3.3223 - acc: 0.1760
1
```

My Code is

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import Model

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

base_model = ResNet50(weights= None, include_top=False, input_shape= (32,32,3))

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
predictions = Dense(10 , activation= 'softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = predictions)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Note that I am using cifar 10 dataset for this model. Is there anything wrong with my code, or with my data? How can I improve this? 1 epoch taking 1 hour is way to long. I have NVIDIA MX-110 2GB too, which ofc TensorFlow is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and ran your code but in order to get it to run I had to make the changes below

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import Model

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
print (len(x_train))
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

base_model = ResNet50(weights= None, include_top=False, input_shape= (32,32,3))

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
predictions = Dense(10 , activation= 'softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = predictions)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, )
# the result for 2 epochs is shown below
50000
Epoch 1/2
1563/1563 [==============================] - 58s 37ms/step - loss: 2.8654 - acc: 0.2537
Epoch 2/2
1563/1563 [==============================] - 51s 33ms/step - loss: 2.5331 - acc: 0.2748
```

Per model.fit documentation if you do not specify the batch size it defaults to 32. So with 50,000 samples/32=1563 steps. For some reason in your code the batch size defaulted to 1.  I do not know why. So set the batch_size=50 and then you will require 1000 steps.
To speed things up more I would set the weights="imagenet" and freeze the layers in the base model with

```
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
#if you set batch_size=50, weights="imagenet" with the base model frozen you get
50000
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/keras-applications/resnet/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5
94773248/94765736 [==============================] - 5s 0us/step
Epoch 1/2
1000/1000 [==============================] - 16s 16ms/step - loss: 2.5101 - acc: 0.1487
Epoch 2/2
1000/1000 [==============================] - 10s 10ms/step - loss: 2.1159 - acc: 0.2249
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you batch your data. As a consequence, each forward pass of the model is only seeing one training instance, which is very inefficient.

Try setting the batch size in your model.fit() call:

```
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=num_epochs, 
                 validation_data=(x_test, y_test), shuffle=True)
```

Tune your batch size so it's the largest that can fit in your GPU's memory - try a few different values before settling on one.